# Multiple streambuilders to filter data in flutter firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

trying to replicate this:[image]

```
    Future<void> getRoomOfSpecificUser() async {
  var users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('users').snapshots();
  var rooms = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collectionGroup('rooms')
      .orderBy('dateCreated', descending: true)
      .snapshots();
  rooms.forEach((roomElement) {
    users.forEach((userElement) {
      for (var rElement in roomElement.docs) {
        for (var uElement in userElement.docs) {
          if (rElement.get('id') == uElement.get('roomId') &&
              uElement.get('userId') == globalAuth.currentUser!.uid) {
            print(rElement.get('id'));
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

[image]

but in this streambuilder
[image]

```
var users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('users').snapshots();
  var rooms = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('rooms')
      .orderBy('dateCreated')
      .snapshots();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder2(
        streams: StreamTuple2(users, rooms),
        builder: (context, snapshots) {
          switch (snapshots.snapshot2.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            case ConnectionState.done:
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshots.snapshot2.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshots.snapshot1.data!.docs[index];
                  print(doc);
                  return Text(doc.get('email').toString());
                },
              );

            default:
              break;
          }
          return Container();
        });
  }
```

also i ***tried*** with an ***array of users*** inside the collection room instead of creating a subcollection of users inside the collection room. but do not know how to modify on specific value inside an array. any help would be awesome, thanks!

```
dependencies:
  multiple_stream_builder: ^3.0.0
```

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots.  Paste actual text of your code.  So much easier to comment on, try, and perhaps even correct for you.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz thanks, i modified it to be more readable and editable

Comment: StreamBuilder2 isn't from the Flutter SDK.  Please include any pubspec references we may also need to understand your code.

Comment: Alright, just added: dependencies:
  multiple_stream_builder: ^3.0.0